# How to get all users besides third REST ASSURED

Tags: java, rest, http, get, rest-assured

Get all users without the third one excluded by name. Verify HTTP response status code. Verify that the third user in not present in response.

How to get all users besides third ?

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
    "username": "Karianne",
    "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
    "address": {
      "street": "Hoeger Mall",
      "suite": "Apt. 692",
      "city": "South Elvis",
      "zipcode": "53919-4257",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "29.4572",
        "lng": "-164.2990"
      }
    },
    "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
    "website": "kale.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Robel-Corkery",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
      "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
    "username": "Kamren",
    "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
    "address": {
      "street": "Skiles Walks",
      "suite": "Suite 351",
      "city": "Roscoeview",
      "zipcode": "33263",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-31.8129",
        "lng": "62.5342"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(254)954-1289",
    "website": "demarco.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Keebler LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
      "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
    "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
    "address": {
      "street": "Norberto Crossing",
      "suite": "Apt. 950",
      "city": "South Christy",
      "zipcode": "23505-1337",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-71.4197",
        "lng": "71.7478"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
    "website": "ola.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Considine-Lockman",
      "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
      "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
    "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
    "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Rex Trail",
      "suite": "Suite 280",
      "city": "Howemouth",
      "zipcode": "58804-1099",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.8918",
        "lng": "21.8984"
      }
    },
    "phone": "210.067.6132",
    "website": "elvis.io",
    "company": {
      "name": "Johns Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
      "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
    "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
    "address": {
      "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
      "suite": "Suite 729",
      "city": "Aliyaview",
      "zipcode": "45169",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-14.3990",
        "lng": "-120.7677"
      }
    },
    "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
    "website": "jacynthe.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Abernathy Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
      "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Glenna Reichert",
    "username": "Delphine",
    "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
    "address": {
      "street": "Dayna Park",
      "suite": "Suite 449",
      "city": "Bartholomebury",
      "zipcode": "76495-3109",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.6463",
        "lng": "-168.8889"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
    "website": "conrad.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Yost and Sons",
      "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
      "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
    "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
    "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
      "suite": "Suite 198",
      "city": "Lebsackbury",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "ambrose.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Hoeger LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: example endpoint ? what have ypu tried >

Comment: I just know how to get users by id but how to get users besides one?
http://localhost:3000/users?id=3&id=4

Comment: how would someone access localhost please add an example response and what have you tried :)

Comment: I think I can do it using HashMap and than pass it to .formParams(params) but maybe I can do it easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use jsonPathfilters if yo uwant to filter with name , else remove by index and get the remaining json:

**Removing by index:**

```
    Response maxJson = RestAssured.given()
            .get("https://praveen.free.beeceptor.com/1");
    JsonPath path  = maxJson.jsonPath();
    path.getList(".").remove(2);
    path.prettyPrint();
```

**filtering**:

```
System.out.println(RestAssured.given()
            .get("https://endpoint.free.beeceptor.com/1")
        .jsonPath().get("findAll { it.id !=  3}").toString());
```